# Objective-C Quick way to compare and replace NSMutableDictionary value

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

I have 2 different length NSMutableDictionary like this:

```
Dic 1: {
0 = 22962;
10 = 11762;
11 = 11762;
12 = 11761;
13 = 11761;
2 = 11762;
3 = 11761;
4 = 11763;
5 = 11763;
6 = 11763;
7 = 11763;
8 = 11763;
9 = 11762;}

Dic 2: {
11756 = "<EPinObject: 0x17009f860>";
11761 = "<EPinObject: 0x17409f950>";
11757 = "<EPinObject: 0x1700973e0>";
11762 = "<EPinObject: 0x17409f9f0>";
11758 = "<EPinObject: 0x174280410>";
11763 = "<EPinObject: 0x17409fa40>";
11759 = "<EPinObject: 0x174280460>";
11760 = "<EPinObject: 0x1742804b0>";
22962 = "<EPinObject: 0x17409f9a0>";}
```

I want to make Dic 3 like this:

```
Dic 3: {
0 = "<EPinObject: 0x17409f9a0>";
10 = "<EPinObject: 0x17409f9f0>";
...
9 = "<EPinObject: 0x17409f9f0>";}
```

Dic 1 have similar value for diff key so i have to put like that

Right now im doing this by using 2 for-in but it seems takes too long and too many loops, i wonder if theres faster way to compare the value of dic1 with key of dic2 and generate the dic3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One for:

```
dict3 = [dict1 mutableCopy]
for (id<NSCopying> key in dict3.allKeys) {
    dict3[key] = dict2[dict3[key]];
}
```

If you don't need to overwrite values that are not present in the `dict2` (for instance, there is `dict1[15] == 12345`, but `dict2[12345] == nil`), you can add a nil check:

```
for (id<NSCopying> key in dict3.allKeys) {
    if (dict2[dict3[key]]) {
        dict3[key] = dict2[dict3[key]];
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:** With @Caleb's improvements (and a little optimization):

```
for (id key in dict1) {
    id dict3Value = dict3[key]; //so we don't have to get this value twice
    if (dict2[dict3Value]) {
        dict3[key] = dict2[dict3Value];
    }
}
```

Comment: @Tj3n, you're welcome :) I updated the answer to use your notation (`dict1`/`dict2`/`dict3`).

Comment: thanks a lot! im still figure out the way to work with keys and values

Comment: Fast enumeration works with dictionaries, so you can drop the `.allKeys`, and I don't think you need the `<NSCopying>` either: `for (id key in dict3) {...`

Comment: @Caleb, thank you for your suggested improvements. However, if we just drop `allKeys`, it will crash (collection was mutated while being enumerated). However, since `dict3` is a copy of `dict1`, we can substitute `dict3` with `dict1` in the `for`. I will add the final version in a moment.